# handle function Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, subscript, function-handle

I'm starting to use functions handles in Matlab and I have a question,
what Matlab computes when I do:

```
y = (0:.1:1)';
fun = @(x) x(1) + x(2).^2 + exp(x(3)*y)
```

and what Matlab computes when I do:

```
fun = @(x) x + x.^2 + exp(x*y)
```

Because I'm evaluating the Jacobian of these functions ([from this code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13490-adaptive-robust-numerical-differentiation) ) and it gives different results. I don't understand the difference of putting x(i) or only x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define a vector `vec` as `vec = [1, 2, 3]`.

When you use this `vec` in your first function as `results = fun(vec)`, the program will take only the particular elements of the vector, meaning `x(1) = vec(1)`, `x(2) = vec(2)` and `x(3) = vec(3)`. The whole expression then will look as

```
results = vec(1) + vec(2).^2 + exp(vec(3)*y)
```

or better

```
results = 1 + 2^2 + exp(3*y)
```

However, when you use your second expression as `results = fun(vec)`, it will use the entire vector `vec` in all the cases like this

```
results = vec + vec.^2 + exp(vec*y)
```

or better

```
results = [1, 2, 3] + [1^2, 2^2, 3^2] + exp([1, 2, 3]*y)
```

You can also clearly see that in the first case, I don't really need to care about matrix dimensions, and the final dimensions of the `results` variable are the same as the dimensions of your `y` variable. This is not the case in the second example, because you multiply matrices `vec` and `y`, which (in this particular example) results in error, as the `vec` variable has dimensions `1x3` and the `y` variable `11x1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to investigate this, I recommend you split this up into subexpressions and debug, e.g.

```
f1 = @(x) x(1);
f2 = @(x) x(2).^2;
f3 = @(x) exp(x(3)*y);
f  = @(x) f1(x) + f1(x) + f3(x)
```

You can split it up even further if any subexpression is unclear.

The distinction is that one is an array array multiplication (`x * y`, I'm assuming x is an array with 11 columns in order for the matrix multiplication to be consistent) and the other is a scalar array multiplication (`x(3) * y`). The subscript operator `(n)` for any matrix extracts the n-th value from that matrix. For a scalar, the index can only be 1. For a 1D array, it extracts the n-th element of the column/row vector. For a 2D array, its the n-th element when traversed columnwise.

Also, if you only require the first derivative, I suggest using complex-step differentiation. It provides reduced numerical error and is computationally efficient.